# Cast off_t to int

Tags: c

I'm getting a "int format, different type arg (arg 4)" error on the last line.  Should I just cast to int or is there a better way to handle this?

```
struct stat info;
if (stat(file_path, &info) == -1 || errno == ENOENT)
    return -1;

if (stat(file_path, &info) != -1)
{
    char buf[LINELEN];
    snprintf(buf,LINELEN,"File Size: %d",info.st_size);
```

Comment: The bad thing about `printf` (and that makes me truly sad) is exactly this problem with the format string. Imagine your code that typedefs a type either to `uint32_t` or `uint64_t` depending on some configuration. You can never just printf those variables. However, the solution that most definitely always work without a problem is to cast the arguments to the maximum size they can assume. In your case for example: `printf("%lu", (unsigned int)info.st_size);` which prints correctly no matter the size. Only problem is if argument is bigger than your cast. You'd lose data, but still avoid UB.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no format defined for `off_t` which may be any signed integer type, depending on the platform and also on some macros (that regulate if you may access files larger than 4 GiB, e.g.). You can't rely on anything of this. The best is to use "j" as a length modifier in your `printf` format and to cast your value to `intmax_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Try format %ld instead. It depends on your platform, but usually off_t is defined as long. Could also be unsigned, in that case use %lu.

Answer (score 0):

For the `off_t` type, you should print it like this:

```
snprintf(buf,LINELEN,"File Size: %jd",info.st_size);
```

Notice the `j` in the formatter.

Comment: the "j" format is for `{u}intmax_t`. So you'd have to cast to that type as well to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

`st_size` is of type `off_t`, which is really a `long`.

So the proper call shall be:

```
snprintf(buf,LINELEN,"File Size: %ld",info.st_size);
```

Comment: "really a long"? It can be any signed integer type.

Comment: so, do you think that the "j" modifier will be present in all implementations? assuming that it is a long is safer. You can cast the st_size to long without any compiler warning: `snprintf(buf,LINELEN,"File Size: %ld", (long)info.st_size);`

Comment: the "j" modifier is part of the C standard. AFAIR this is so since C99.

Answer (score 0):

To be safe, correct and portable: always include an explicit cast when passing varargs, for example to printf, if the thing you're passing might not have the same type wherever you compile. For example, work out how big you think off_t can get (long should be at least as big as an off_t everywhere), cast to that, and make sure your printf format accepts the long that you now safely know you'll be passing in. A printf without a cast for types that may vary is asking for trouble.